# How can I upload a Dynamics webresource build with webpack for AppSource?

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamics-crm, office-store, appsource

I have a vue.js project build with webpack. It's a webresource for Dynamics CRM. To upload it to the AppSource it has to pass the Power Apps Checker, but the compiled javascript files offend against many rules. These rules are the worst:

- Do not directly handle the DOM (50 times)
- Do not directly access the DOM (113 times)
- Do not assume that the parent window is the entity form (796 times)

Almost every line generated by webpack offends at least one rule, because it uses statements like `document.getElmentById`, `document.createElement` or `addEventListener`, which are all forbidden for AppSource-Apps.

How can I pass the AppSource Checker, and still use webpack to build the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just talk with Microsoft. If you use a webresource in an iframe, they will allow those functions. You just have to explain the usage of those lines.
(sorry for the late answer)